# Magento 2 add custom product attribute validation from install script

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, form-validation, knockoutjs

```
[
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'XXXX',
    'input' => 'text',
    'frontend_class' => 'validate-greater-than-zero',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => true,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false
]
```

I am adding custom product attribute which works fine, but not able to add `validate-greater-than-zero` validation.

If we look at any attribute properties in `Input Validation for Store Owner` there are limited number of validations in select options.

`validate-number`,`validate-digits`,`validate-email`,`validate-url`,`validate-alpha`,`validate-alphanum`

These are the only validations applied in Product attribute section.

Comment: Please see my answer, it will be helping you to validate your attribute value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the help of `Matthéo Geoffray`, this is what I did to apply frontend validation for custom attributes.

```
[
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'XXXX',
    'input' => 'text',
    'frontend_class' => 'validate-greater-than-zero',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => true,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false
]
```

This is the custom attribute in install script.

I added plugin in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules">
      <plugin name="namespace_custom_validation_for_product_attribute" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\Product\ValidationRules"/>
</type>
```

Here is the plugin code.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\Product;

use Closure;

class ValidationRules
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundBuild(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
        array $data
    ){
        $rules = $proceed($attribute,$data);
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'xyz'){ //custom filter
            $validationClasses = explode(' ', $attribute->getFrontendClass());
            foreach ($validationClasses as $class) {
                $rules[$class] = true;
            }
        }
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Basically in `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules`, the method called `mapRules` only matches the frontend class against limited number of validation rules. To apply more validation rules we need to append rules using plugin.

For server side validation, Please refer to `Matthéo Geoffray` answer.

Answer (score 20):

One of the solution is to add a `backend model` to your attribute which is used to format / validate your attribute value before save and/or after load.

Add a backend class :

```
[
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '\Foo\Bar\Model\Attribute\Backend\YourAttribute',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'XXXX',
    'input' => 'text',
    'frontend_class' => 'validate-greater-than-zero',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => true,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false
]
```

Here is an example of your custom class `\Foo\Bar\Model\Attribute\Backend\YourAttribute`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Model\Attribute\Backend;

/**
 * Class YourAttribute
 */
class YourAttribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{

    /**
     * @var int $minimumValueLength
     */
    protected $minimumValueLength = 0;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterLoad($object)
    {
        // your after load logic

        return parent::afterLoad($object);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $this->validateLength($object);

        return parent::beforeSave($object);
    }

    /**
     * Validate length
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function validateLength($object)
    {
        /** @var string $attributeCode */
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        /** @var int $value */
        $value = (int)$object->getData($attributeCode);
        /** @var int $minimumValueLength */
        $minimumValueLength = $this->getMinimumValueLength();

        if ($this->getAttribute()->getIsRequired() && $value <= $minimumValueLength) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('The value of attribute "%1" must be greater than %2', $attributeCode, $minimumValueLength)
            );
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimum attribute value length
     * 
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinimumValueLength()
    {
        return $this->minimumValueLength;
    }
}
```

If you want a simple example of that kind of class you can check

- `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Website`
- all the classes which extend
  `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend`
- the classes into `backend_model` column in `eav_attribute` table

---

**EDIT**
If you want a class that do nearly the same thing as you want you can take a look at the `SKU` attribute validation `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Sku`
I also added the method in the example class

---

**EDIT**
Another solution (maybe not the best one) is to create a plugin on the function `\Magento\Eav\Helper\Data::getFrontendClasses` and add your frontend class here that can be validated in front.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but would it be possible to apply  frontend validation.

Comment: If you take a look at your attribute line in `eav_attribute` table in the column `frontend_class` is thee the value `validate-greater-than-zero` ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. These are the only classes which works `validate-number`,`validate-digits`,`validate-email`,`validate-url`,`validate-alpha`,`validate-alphanum`.

Comment: Can you try my second **edit**, to add your custom frontend classes ?

Comment: I did it using plugin, thanks for the hint

Comment: OK great ! Can you apply the bounty as well please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it could be possible from install script.
But I'm sure it's possible if you will create "before listener plugin" with function `beforeSave()` and check value there.