# Magento 2: Custom validation on product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, validation

There are only six validation available for product attributes

> 1. validate-number (Decimal Number)
> 2. validate-digits (Integer Number)
> 3. validate-email (Email)
> 4. validate-url (URL)
> 5. validate-alpha (Letters)
> 6. validate-alphanum (Letters (a-z, A-Z) or Numbers (0-9))

I follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153244/magento-2-add-custom-product-attribute-validation-from-install-script) and add new(Value Greater than 0) validation to product attribute with the upgradeData script.

**But it uses backend class for validate attribute value and validate value at the time of saving attribute. But I want JS validation which should working on tab key.**

Have anyone an idea about custom JS validation on product attribute?

Comment: is your js customisation need for the frontend or for the backend, are you able to describe how you'd be using this js validation you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write js validation functions like validate-email and other functions you mentioned.
You can write your custom funtion in rules.js by overriding it in this way:

Vendor file :

`vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\lib\validation\rules.js`

Override file in custom theme :

`app/design/frontend/Package/themename/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`

There is already a function for value greater than 0:

```
validate-greater-than-zero
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create custom validation for greater than zero as default magento already has that validation class. you can see in Product Add/Edit form > Advanced Pricing > Tire Price Qty Box. It does not allow value less than zero.
For more information check this file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AdvancedPricing.php